# How can I make router connect to internet through computer?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, wireless-router, hotspot

Some asked [a similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/318179/how-can-i-make-my-router-connect-to-the-internet-through-a-computer) previously, but the answer did not work for me.

My modem broke but I have an Optimum WiFi hotspot near me that I can connect to. However , only 1 of my computers is able to connect to it. Therefore, I want to connect that computer to my router (Belkin WGR614v7) and then have the router provide internet to the other computers in the house.

I am currently using a dell with windows 7, and built in Wireless and Ethernet.

This is the answer I tried from the other question:

```
Set up sharing on COMPUTER with 3G (working internet)
Set up static ip address on COMPUTER with 3G (192.168.5.1 or so)
Connect your COMPUTER with 3G to WAN port on ROUTER
Set up static ip address on WAN settings with GATEWAY pointing to 192.168.5.1 - Ip address from range 192.168.5.X), as DNS servers you could use some google servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4
Enjoy :-) As long as you've shared your connection on COMPUTER properly you should be fine."
```

I am confused about some details. For example, which ip to set static on comp, LAN or wireless and TCP4 or TCP4? Also, does this call for 2 simultaneous wireless connections and how is this possible?

Comment: Do you have a Belkin WGR614v7 or a [Netgear WGR614v7](http://support.netgear.com/product/WGR614v7)?

Answer (score 2):

I think instead of looking at the SuperUser question you found look at [this page on Internet Connection Sharing (ICS)](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/Using-ICS-Internet-Connection-Sharing) on the Microsoft Website.

The answer you are quoting from is probably not the best one to use because it is based on sharing a connection from a [Cellular 3G](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3G) connection, not a WiFi connection like an Optimum hotspot.

As an alternative solution, see if you can make your router act as a wireless client, as opposed to a wireless access point, you can simply have that connect to the Optimum hotspot. You can then turn a Windows 7 computer with a wired connection to your router into a hotspot with the [virtual router project](http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I tried to follow the directions on http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Sharing-one-Internet-connection-among-several-computers but didn't succeed. I can connect the router to both computers but as soon as I enable network sharing on the first it renames the router an unidentified network, the the second computer still isn't getting internet from it. DO I have to set up any special settings on the router.
P.S. The router is capable of both wired and wireless connections and is connected to comp 1 (the one with internet) through ethernet.

Comment: I also read a couple guides, like this one http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1080 , that mention turning off DHCP or setting static routes, but am wasn't able to succeed using them. Not sure if this is because I couldn't understand something or because they weren't written for quiet the same device and some options didn't appear on my router. Should I be trying something like this or is it too complicated and not needed?

Comment: Turn off DHCP on your router. Its up to you to find out how to do that for your specific model